# Unable to change Formik forms text field

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, formik

I am using the following code:

```
<Formik initialValues={{val:cell.value}}>
  <Form>
    <Field type="text" name="val" size="2" onChange = {(e)=> {console.log(e.target)}}></Field>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

and I am unable to change the value at UI. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Formik should be handling the changes. See the following example: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik

Note that the input in the example is triggering Formik's handleChange in the onChange:

```
onChange={props.handleChange}
```

Answer (score 1):

**App.js**

I used [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) and [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
const App = () => {
  const cell = { value: "test" };
  const [myVal, setMyVal] = useState(cell.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <Formik initialValues={{ val: cell.value }}>
        <Form>
          <Field
            type="text"
            name="val"
            size="20"
            placeholder="type something"
            value={myVal}
            onChange={e => {
              console.log(e.target.value);
              setMyVal(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

check out the [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60169172-formik)

Answer (score 0):

In your onChange, you need to update the state, which then gets passed back into Formik. Right now you are just outputting the value.